# why contact form 7 returns empty content

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, contact-form

I use this contact form 7 to generate a bit more custom form but on the test that I did, I get a mail without the content. How can I solve this issue?

```
<div class="form-group">

 <p>[text* text-375 placeholder "Your name"]</p>

 <p>[text* text-878 placeholder "Your e-mail"]</p>

</div>

<p>[textarea textarea-949 40x9 placeholder "Your message"]</p>

[submit "buy now"]
```

Form Message Body

```
From: [your-name] <[email]>
Subject: [your-subject]

Message Body:
[your-message]

-- 
This e-mail was sent from a contact form on [_site_title] ([_site_url])
```

The content of the received email:

```
From: [name] <[email]>
Subject: [subject]

Message Body:
[message]

--
This e-mail was sent from a contact form on XXX XXX (https://XXXX.com)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<div class="form-group">

 <p>[text* name placeholder "Your name"]</p>

 <p>[email* email placeholder "Your e-mail"]</p>

</div>

<p>[textarea message 40x9 placeholder "Your message"]</p>

[submit "buy now"]
```

**Form Message Body:**

```
From: [name]  <[email]>

Message Body:
[message]

-- 
This e-mail was sent from a contact form on [_site_title] ([_site_url])
```